# VBScript calculations - VBscript error - when a data field is NULL or 0

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

This is the piece of code im having an issue with.

```
<%=total+((rs("fee_overall")/100)*rs("fee_wip")-rs("fee_rendered"))%>
```

If any of the data fields are either 0 or *NULL* then i get a mismatch error

"Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d' Type mismatch: '[string: ""]' "

Any help is apreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide more info what your code is suppose to do, nobody can guess what your issue is without your full code and explained details, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is in ASP.... the calculation is using data fields that are on sql.

Comment: if the fields are null or 0 than it falls over, however if say - fee_overall = 200, fee_wip = 50, fee_rendered = 25 then i get 75 which is correct...

Answer (score 0):

in this case **Zero** seems to be ok because you have no division by zero. for null variables the standard solution would be that you check if variables are not null , then do calculations:

```
    if not(isnull(rs("feeoveral")) or isnull( rs("fee_wip")) or isnull(rs("fee_rendered")) ) then
    response.write total+((rs("fee_overall")/100)*rs("fee_wip")-rs("fee_rendered"))
    else
    response.write "bolb"
    end if
```

Comment: (a) Null + 0 = Null (b) Null <> Null throws Invalid use of Null (c) IsNull() is the way to test for Null - Test your code before you post.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
    Dim fee_over

    If (IsNull(rs("fee_overall"))) Then
    fee_over = "0"
    Else
    fee_over = (rs("fee_overall"))
    End If
response.write total+((Cint(fee_over))/100)
```

Also please check that your database record is INT and default 0

Comment: Please reconsider your `fee_over = "0"`. What do you hope to achieve by using a string ("0") instead of a number?

Comment: Because of his mismatch seems like he is already set his column as a varchar. But you are right. it should be given = 0

Comment: ok - ive changed the field values to INT (was nvarchar) but now i get this - Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000b' 

Division by zero 

/LRW/Result_Fee_page.asp, line 151

Comment: line 151 is -   `<td style="width: 156px"><%=FormatNumber(total+((1-(rs("Job_Costs")/((rs("fee_Overall_2")/100)*rs("fee_WIP"))))*100),0)%>%</td> `